# xHTML correctness question and quick CSS float question

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float, html-lists

I'm just writing to inquire what would be more correct for xHTML and a CSS question.

For the HTML:

Say I have a list of:
Apples,
Bananas,
and Carrots

Would this be more correct:

```
<ul> <li> Apples </li> <li>  Bananas </li> <li> Carrots </li> </ul>
```

Or would this be:

```
<ol> <li> Apples </li> <li>  Bananas </li> <li> Carrots </li> </ol>
```

For CSS, after an element has been floated, which attribute can be used to restore flow to block alignment?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Depends on the context of the list. ul = unorderred list in no paticular order, ol = ordered list in a specific order. For the float, you mean removing the float? Float: none.

Comment: @l3fty Right, I know the difference between the two, but what would be more correct for the situation? Also, I think there is something you can call to restore flow around a floated element? I'm not too sure what it is, though.

Comment: Like I said, depends on the context. Apples, Bananas, Carrots provides no context. If you're just listing fruit it would be unordered list in no specific order. I am not exactly sure what you mean by restore the flow. Maybe you're talking about [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)?

Comment: The situation where the list is ordered, for example in alphabetical order, and where this is part of the meaning of the list then ol would be suitable but if it's just any old list of fruit and it won't matter if say mango is inserted at the top then ul would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` element stands for "unordered list" which implies it was ordered to begin with (the proper English approach would be `no` for non-ordered). The `ol` element stands for "ordered list". Is this list intentionally ordered or not? If you order them alphabetically then I'd considered using the `ul` element since it's more of a technicality and not some life-or-death importance.

You can work with `display` and `float` together. Generally speaking you should look in to the [CSS display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). As `flexbox` support has improved and the bugs have been ironed out I've migrated to using it and reserving `float` for neat tricks like applying it to an image nested within a bunch of paragraph elements.

Also something people who make six figures have no idea about: XHTML and HTML5 aren't opposed. My platform uses the XML *parser* while the code is HTML5. A parser takes text and determines how to interpret it for processing. The XML parser is very strict (though not perfectly strict and each browser engine varies, currently Gecko's has been superior) while the HTML parser doesn't mind if there are hobos all over your front lawn and will likely invite even more while it *knows* you're watching.